# Web Portal Integration with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a concern on how to integrate SharePoint 2016 with a web portal.(custom API, BDC...)
for example, if i have an HR recruiting solution on SharePoint and i want to show the available vacancies created on SharePoint on the company website.
Any suggestions how should i start my research?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

- Run a nightly job using the SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets or C# code and the SharePoint Server API to collect the data and write it to somewhere your web site could read it.
- Use the SharePoint REST API from your web site code to directly read the list data. Something like:

  ```
  https://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Vacancies')/items?$select=Name,Description&$filter=Status eq 'Active'
  ```

References:

Choose the right API set in SharePoint
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint

Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Comment: Mike Smith, thank you for your reply.

for the first point, do you think that BDC can be a good option for me? i will save the pulled data in a list so i can run some workflows on it. (i need to know also when someone apply for a job)
How to give the access to the web site to read data from my SharePoint list?
any idea if there is an article about this process step by step done by some seniors? to follow it or to have an idea about how the development should be done.